# Low branch coverage especially when using 3rd party libs. ex boost

Tags: c++, boost, code-coverage, gcovr

I have problems understanding branch coverage in c++. Even for a simple program the branch coverage is 50%. When i use boost the branch coverage is below 20%.

[image]

Could someone explain me why this is happening? I am using

```
-fno-exceptions -g -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fPIC -Wall
```

compiler flags and `gcovr` for generating the report. I also tried `lcov` with exactly the same result

Answer (score 3):

This is just general C++ compiler weirdness. Both gcovr and lcov depend on the coverage data that GCC measures within the object code, and the compiler seems to insert some branch statements there.

I've looked at the [disassembly of the generated code on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/2zStTm), and the compiler does indeed insert two `jne` branch instructions under a section `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0`. These disappear when you compile with `-O1`.

Which optimization levels you should pick for your coverage measurements is a bit tricky. The more optimizations you enable, the more difficult it is to tie a coverage measurement to a specific source code line because the compiler may optimize much code away. But with C++, some optimizations are expected, and it's confusing when the compiler produces unnecessary code. As is the case here. Whatever level you choose, you won't generally be able to achieve full branch coverage.

The gcov documentation also discusses [using gcov with GCC optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-and-Optimization.html#Gcov-and-Optimization). Gcov is used by gcovr to process the raw coverage data, and therefore has the same limitations.

However, gcovr performs some post-processing where it can exclude branches on lines that don't carry source code. Here, this would ignore any branches on the `}` line when given the `--exclude-unreachable-branches` flag.

Comment: Using `-O1` did not bring any advantage to me. On the contrary, I got one branch less covered and got more line coverage, which is of course wrong. Using `--exclude-unreachable-branches` option from gcovr didn't make any difference. I think the best solution would be to find if there is a gcc compiling option to avoid extra code generation.

Comment: @ArturoGonzalez the compiler can't avoid branches where they are needed for correct C/C++ semantics. You will never get 100% branch coverage reported by gcov-based tools, unless you use advanced testing methods like failure injection. If the extra branches you see are due to exception handling, you can try the new `gcovr --exclude-throw-branches` option (not yet released, you have to install the development version straight from GitHub).